# How to modify an installed gem on Windows?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

So I've installed svn2git using Ruby on Windows. Unfortunately, since git has made the change of Master branch to Main, this has broken the script. I've found the script in

```
C:\Ruby27-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.7.0\gems\svn2git-2.4.0
```

and made the required modifications. How do I recompile / remake this so that when I run `svn2git` on the command line it uses my modified script?

Comment: Is this a Perl thing or a Ruby thing? You seem to indicate both here.

Comment: If this is just a gem then you can edit in-place and the next time you run the command it'll load the altered version. If you want that change to persist you should either fork the gem source and install from that fork, or raise an issue with the gem's maintainer(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> since git has made the change of Master branch to Main, this has broken the script

I'm not sure what you mean by "broken"; perhaps you needed to rename `master`-->`main` [here](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git/blob/6dac85ad12b74b478a926f09db0b110d73838702/lib/svn2git/migration.rb#L340)? (Or even better, you could make it somehow *configurable*, not hardcoded?)

> How do I recompile / remake

This is ruby. It's an interpreted language; you don't need to compile anything.

It would be "bad practice" to edit the gem directly on your machine, but this should still *work*. If you run `svn2git` on the command line right now, then - assuming that's the correct installation (e.g. you don't also have a ruby 2.6 version installed that's getting picked up?!), it should run your modified code instead.

---

But for a "better" long-term solution, it would be advisable to [fork the project](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git), make your change, and install your own version of the project.

You could also open a pull request with your change, in case the original author is still active and willing to release an update.

Comment: Thanks for the full answer. The rename is the change I had made, nice simple find and reeplace. And for some reason just running svn2git after that was running the original even after I modified; possbily Windows was moving it elswhere? Either way, `gem build` got it working with my changes.

Comment: I'd like to PR, but seems to have been dead for a while

Comment: The author is still active on github -- so why not make a PR and see? And like I said, you could always re-publish it under a new name, on your own account, for anyone else to use in future. That's the spirit of open source software development.